# what can I infer if my data follows power law?

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, inference, power-law

I am working on data set of "Number of days taken to get a reply to mail". I have studied [Power-law distributions in empirical data](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062) by Aaron Clauset Cosma Rohilla Shalizi and M. E. J. Newman.
I have used powerLaw package in R to find if my data is well fit by a power law.
It shows that power law is a good fit for my data.

I am in basic learning stage of statistics.I have gone through many research papers but could not get the inferences made if data follows power law.
Please help me understand what can I infer if my data is well fit by power law??

Comment: so far i understand that 1) you have data that follows a power law, 2) you have read other papers that deal with stuff that has nothing to do with power laws and 3) you want to generalize these papers' methods to be able to deal with data that follows a power law. If you are asking us about generalizing a method, then you might want to describe that method, and also its task.

Comment: Thank you for the response.I read papers that are related to power law such as "How popular is your paper -S. Redner","POWER-LAW DISTRIBUTIONS IN EMPIRICAL DATA- AARON CLAUSET" etc., in which they fitted power law to various data sets. What I am trying to understand is 1) If a data set is following power law what inferences can we draw from that. For example in my data as it is following power law what inferences can I draw?From the study I have done I understood one inference can be1)it follows 80-20 rule "80% of my mails are taking 20% time". Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what, specifically, you are looking for in the way of "inference" wrt power laws but this paper by Gabix *Power Laws in Economics and Finance: An Introduction* might be a good place to start. http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~xgabaix/papers/pl-ar.pdf

Comment: If you show your data, we can likely figure out what can be done with it faster than you can explain what you want.

Comment: This paper by Sornette and Bouchaud has a long list of references regarding the behaviors of power law distributed information, *Taming Large Events*, https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b31e/5c15a2ba3f0df2019cdd8720412fd5d026d0.pdf

Comment: The Clauset paper outlines a procedure to test goodness of fit of a power-law distribution, so you're consulting the correct resource. Can you elaborate on what part of the paper is giving you trouble, or what specifically you need help understanding?